# Salesforce Case Creation

Tags: case, c#

Ok this is a stab in the dark but I figured I would ask here since i'm not sure when my salesforce ticket will be answered. This is also live not sandbox.

Here is the error

```
"A workflow or approval field update caused an error when saving this record. Contact your administrator to resolve it.
Original Priority: data value too large: SLA - 2 - Enterprise Level and/or Practice Level Failure (max length=50)"
```

There is no workflow rule that has anything to do with this error according to our salesforce admin. If I set this to another value 50 or under it works but it says the length is 255?

I'm creating a case via code we have the following field in Case

```
Field name: Priority__c
Field Label: Priority
Type is: picklist
Length: 255
This is a custom field.
Can be nulled.
Createable
Filterable
Updateable
Picklist Values
    SLA - 0 - High Priority User Issue
    SLA - 1 - Enterprise Level System Failure
    SLA - 1 - System Failure
    SLA - 2 - Enterprise Level and/or Practice Level Failure
    SLA - 2 - Enterprise Level Major Issue
    SLA - 2 - Major Issue
    SLA - 3 - Enterprise Level and/or Practice Level Issue
    SLA - 3 - Enterprise Level Moderate Issue
    SLA - 3 - Moderate / Minor Normal Issue
    SLA - 4 - Client Request / Client Created Issue
    SLA - 4 - Enterprise Level Minor Issue
    SLA - 4 - Practice Level Issue
    SLA - 5 - Client Request / Client Created Issue
    SLA - 5 - Third Party or Non Supportable Issue
    SLA - 6 - Third Party or Non Supportable Issue
    SLA - 7 - High Priority Maintenance Request
    SLA - 7 - Payer Issue
    SLA - 8 - Internal Resource Service Request
    SLA - 8 - Non-Issue
    SLA - 9 - Service Request
```

Here is how I am creating the sObject in code

```
    Case salesForceCase = new Case();
salesForceCase.AccountId = accountID;
salesForceCase.ContactId = contactID;
salesForceCase.Subject = salesForceCaseData.Subject;
salesForceCase.Type = salesForceCaseData.CaseType;
salesForceCase.Product_Category__c = salesForceCaseData.Product;
salesForceCase.Product_Subcategory__c = salesForceCaseData.SubProduct;
salesForceCase.Priority__c = salesForceCaseData.SLA;

//default from
salesForceCase.Origin = "Support Console";

//default status
salesForceCase.Status = "Case Opened";

salesForceCase.Description = salesForceCaseData.Description;
salesForceCase.Subject = salesForceCaseData.Subject;

//put name and phone in other contact incase it's different then one assoc with email
//this could be if they are using someone elses email which does happen
StringBuilder fullName = new StringBuilder();
fullName.Append(salesForceCaseData.FirstName);
fullName.Append(" ");
fullName.Append(salesForceCaseData.LastName);

salesForceCase.To_Contact_not_in_SF__c = fullName.ToString();
salesForceCase.To_Contact_Phone__c = salesForceCaseData.PhoneNumber;

if (CreateBatch(salesForceCase)) { do stuff }
```

Here is CreateBatch

```
sObject[] sObj = new sObject[1];
sObj[0] = sObject;
SaveResult[] results = sf.create(sObj);

if (results[0].success)
{
   return true;
}
   else
{
   return false;
}
```

Any insight would be great. Is there some limitation with the API? Just not understanding why I get this error.

Comment: Where are you seeing that error?  On page or in debug logs?

Comment: results[0].errors[0] contains it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workflow rule written on case object which tries to update native field "Priority" from custom field . "Priority" field has `maxlength=50`. That is why you are facing this error. Your logic is correct but automation not.

Answer (score 0):

So it isn't a limitation of the API, because I don't see where you are actually using the API.  Looks to be 100% in Apex.

I don't want to call your admin a liar, but that error sounds way to specific to not be associated with a workflow or approval step.  My recommendation is to setup a debug log and see how the entire transaction is flowing, this will often point to where in the process it failed and which workflow or approval is associated with the error.

I think what is happening is your admin is looking for the error in the workflow/approval ... and it actually looks like a validation rule to me.  So the workflow is trying to update the field value and validation rule is blocking it.

Comment: It looks like C# with SOAP API to me.